# What do you call this technique?

Tags: sampling, modeling, references, binomial-distribution, algorithms

I'm a worker in the energy business, and I'm trying to see if we can predict whether a customer will complain given that they called in about x, y and z. My team and I are new to data science.

In the data there are about $200$ call reasons.

The way we tried to do this before was to construct a sparse matrix which tells you how many times customer $i$ calls in about $j$. The final column is whether $i$ complained in 2015. Sadly it appears that more than 30% of customers who've called in have complained. We tried random forests (70% accuracy), naive bayes (54% accuracy) and JRip (70% accuracy). All of these were cross-validated. Previously some people tried this task out and made a random forest model with 85% OOB accuracy. I don't know how they managed that.

Anyway I've been thinking about a different approach. The aim is to estimate the probability $\operatorname p(s)$ that a customer whose call reasons form the [bag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) $s$ will complain. Pseudocode:

$\text{let } h \text{ be a hash table where the indices are bags and the entries are 2-vectors}\\
\text{for row }r \text{ in data}:\\
\text{  }h[\text{the bag of call reasons in }r][r.\text{didComplain}] \text{ += } 1$

Then $\operatorname{p}(s)\approx {h[s][1] \over h[s][0] + h[s][1]}$

After discussion with someone we reasoned that if we found someone who didn't complain with call reasons $s$ we should increment $h[s'][0]$ for every *sub*bag $s'$ of $s$. If on the other hand they did complain we would increment $h[s'][1]$ where $s'$ is every *super*bag of $s$. I've decided to omit the pseudocode.

What do you call this? Is it a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your (pseudo)-code right, you are counting number of calls mentioning one specific call reason, and number of them which are classified as a complaint. So what you are calculating is simply called **the relative frequency of complaints**.  It can be seen as an estimator of the probability of (this specific) complaint.

You can see the number of complaints as a random variable with a **binomial distribution**, and based on that you can calculate a confidence interval for the probability of complaint.